# Does the WebClient in C# have any unusual headers set by default?

Tags: c#, rest, webclient

I am trying to post a WPF form to my server, but I keep getting a 401 unauthorized response, even though I am sending the correct details.

This is my c# code

```
// Send the ComputerSettings to the API
String _Url = this.ApiUrl + "/api/hospitals/settings.xml";
String _Parameters = "";
_Parameters += "access_token=" + Authentication.AccessToken;
_Parameters += "&hospital_id=" + txtHospital.Text;
_Parameters += "&username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtUsername.Text);
_Parameters += "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtPassword.Password);

Debug.WriteLine(_Url + "?" + _Parameters);

WebClient _WebClient = new WebClient();
_WebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
_WebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
_WebClient.UploadString(_Url, _Parameters);
```

When I run this from Visual Studio the Server returns a 401 unauthorized. But when I copy the url from Debug into into a REST Chrome Client (I use DHC in case that is important) then POST from there, the request works as expected.

My best guess is that Visual Studio is encoding the url parameters in an unexpected way. But I can't figure out what it is doing that is different. I also can't see a way to inspect the response contents, which would allow me to dump the data that the server is seeing into the response and debug it. I've tried things like

```
_ResponseString = _WebClient.UploadString(_Url, _Parameters);
Debug.WriteLine(_ResponseString);
```

But the exception is thrown before that Debug line, and when I inspect the Exception, the response has no contents.

edit:
I see my mistake, I'm sending the parameters as a query string in my REST client, but as request parameters from Visual Studio. The fix (for this example) is to change the UploadString call to

```
_WebClient.UploadString(_Url + "?" + _Parameters, "");
```

Comment: Have you tried using a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark to see the HTTP request that's actually getting sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make the solution to this more visible I'm going to post my edit as an answer

> edit: I see my mistake, I'm sending the parameters as a query string
>   in my REST client, but as request parameters from Visual Studio. The
>   fix (for this example) is to change the UploadString call to

```
_WebClient.UploadString(_Url + "?" + _Parameters, "");
```

> instead of

```
_WebClient.UploadString(_Url, _Parameters);
```